# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. XIV (we skipped a number, I know)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

(We skipped a number to avoid bad luck!)

(READ THE SOLUTION TO PT. VIII BEFORE CONTINUING)

---

You lead the hiker through passageway

> V

and you both seem to be alive by the time you come into a giant, rotunda-like room.

“Okay,” you say. “Explain.”

“Yeah,” he says, “I guess I owe you that.”

You nod emphatically.

“Okay, well here goes…”

And so, the hiker tells his story… and you don’t believe one bit of it! His story is:

*After what happened on the street that night, I was so scared! I ran all the way to Switzerland and hid there. I heard whispers of what I had done in some places, but only one person figured out that it was me. Her name was Misty Yvonne Rickmann Torrean Henderson, but she called herself MYRTH (her initials). She claimed that she was a psychic, and could see all that had happened in my past. Of course, I was hesitant. Then, she proved herself to me. She also told me another thing: that I had a [nibling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nibling), and that they would find me if I left a trail for them to follow. You followed it. I’m your uncle...*

Then, he started sobbing uncontrollably.

---

Obviously, you say, “Yeah, uh-huh, and I’m MYRTH’s child!”

His eyes widen, “How did you know that?”

You snort and say, “Let’s get on with this labyrinth, I’m hungry. Then we’ll figure out what to do with you.”

He quivers nervously.

---

There are five passageways around the rotunda (not including the one you just came through). Each is labeled with a letter:

- M
- Y
- R
- T
- H

You gasp.

“You see?” the hiker says, triumphant.

You are certain that he must have set this up somehow, but decide to move on. There is an inscription on the wall, once more. It reads:

`VeetOnuIZnor(ypSrVnn}eThHsnch{fnacsaAlT[riyBcsnsympelinhteniCZiPBnDiaSicuZEW]fosdulaeFesl)lytiI[(i}AHlAeadtAOslAaSneriayarohrafM]AZ{tDyZo)clMdec`

---

**Which passage should you take, and why?**

---

**Current Points:**
Joshua Bizley -- <strike>24</strike> <strike>19</strike> 14 points

Shoover -- <strike>15</strike> <strike>40</strike> 109 points

Omega Krypton — <strike>40</strike> <strike>60</strike> 67 points

SEE PART XI FOR INFORMATION ON HOW POINTS WORK

IF THE BOUNTY ENDS AND NOBODY HAS ANSWERED CORRECTLY, I WILL POST THE CORRECT ANSWER AND WE WILL MOVE ON

---

Oh my gosh! Boatload of information, but -- apparently -- we’re just not ready to believe it, yet… Maybe something else will be revealed in Part XV! P.S. So sorry about any confusion the part number may have caused! We had to skip over a specific number! The number skip has absolutely nothing to do with the actual puzzle. I just wanted to avoid bad luck!

---

## Hint 0.23182 (FREE!)

I realized that I should have included more information in the original puzzle, so I'm posting it as a free hint. Sorry about that, everyone! Unfortunately, I made this hint as obscure as possible, please forgive me!

> German -- U + 90 deg CC :

## Hint 1 (7% point deduction)

> Think *rotations* in relation to the free hint...

## Hint 2 (8% further deduction)

> CC... Hmmm... CommonCore? Nah. What about carbon copy? That can't be right. Wait! Counter...?

## Hint 3 (10% further deduction)

> https://learn-german-easily.com/german-umlauts

## Hint 4 (20% further deduction)

> Think WWI and German U's with umlauts...

## Hint 5 (45% further deduction)

> Check out the revision history under hint 4... This bonus hint was always there, you just didn't think to check for it, did you?

## Hint 6 (55% further deduction)

> http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/

## Hint 7 (75% further deduction) <-- 4 pts maximum (all or nothing)

> http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/ubchi.php

There shall be no more hints! This is rather disappointing, to be honest...

Comment: Well, a rot13(lbh gjb friragl vf n trezna fhoznevar), but I don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: @shoover - I see you've caught some red herring, there! I'm only revealing this now because the third hint should make it obvious that that was a red herring...

Comment: I hadn't actually come back to notice that there were any hints after the free one!

Comment: @shoover - Now you have a chance at gaining some points! Current maximum is 77 points because of the deductions...

Comment: Sorry, @shoover, I should have been a little bit clearer. What you found is actually helpful in finding out the result (_sort_ of), but is still technically a red herring...

Comment: "Boatload of information" was this intentional?

Comment: @Duck - Nah, that's just my commentary.

Comment: @shoover - Another hint! The bounty ends tomorrow!! After the bounty ends, I won't award _any_ points so hints will also be coming fast.

Comment: Do you want to take a guess, @Duck?

Comment: I not very good at cryptography, but I'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take passageway

> T

because

> the etching has been encrypted using the Ubchi cipher (This is hinted by the fact that a U with a colon rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise forms a U with an umlaut. Also, U-boats were first used by Germany in WWI, and Ubchi was a cipher they used during WWI.), with duplicates numbered backwards. If we use the keyword `Misty Yvonne Rickmann Torrean Henderson`, we get MyFirstHalfIsEssentiallyAnOnionAndAVerySecurePlaceToBe{[(space)]}MySecondHalfIsSimplyAVariationOfADitchButTrulyAChannelWhichDrains({[end})].

This is

> a clue as to which passageway to take. The first half describes the Tor browser (Tor standing for The Onion Router). It is a very secure "place to be." The second half is describing a *drainage channel* (a channel which drains). This is called a reen, though is sometimes spelled as "rean."

Now, we can

> put the two together: $Tor+rean=Torrean$.This is one of MYRTH's initials, and so we should take passageway ***T***.

Nobody will receive points for this, though @Duck will probably receive half the bounty (25 rep). Hopefully, Part XV will be posted in the next couple days!

Comment: @Duck - You'll get half the bounty, most likely...

Comment: Awww! So close!

Comment: @Duck - Yes, you were. Just missed the second half!

Comment: But I was right about taking passage t...

Comment: @Duck - Yes, but the points were all-or-nothing because there were only four of them... Feel free to upvote this answer! :D

Comment: @Duck - Thanks :) You'll get your 25 rep in 37-ish minutes, still. Congratulations on getting as far as you did! Hopefully Part XV won't require as many hints!

Comment: Ok, I'll watch out for the next one!

Comment: @Duck - Darn, I forgot about the grace period...

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer (more probably coming)

> So I go to http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/ubchi.php to decrypt it, use the keyword Misty Yvonne Rickmann Torrean Henderson, use the duplicates numbered backward option and I get this:
>  MyFirstHalfIsEssentiallyAnOnionAndAVerySecurePlaceToBe{[(space)]}MySecondHalfIsSimplyAVariationOfADitchButTrulyAChannelWhichDrains({[end})]  Here it is with the spaces: My first half is essentially an onion and a very secure place to be. My second half is simply a variation of a ditch but truly a channel which drains

> Credit to @shoover for this, but maybe this means tor tunnel (tunnel t) because of the onion is in the tor logo and tor is a safe place to be. A tunnel is a variation of a ditch but truly a channel which drains.

Comment: rot13(gur svefg unys fbhaqf yvxr GBE)

Comment: rot13(frpbaq unys GHAARY?)

Comment: Interesting thoughts! You're certainly very close, but the four points are all-or-nothing, so...